# Android Ionic keyboard Scroll issue

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, android-softkeyboard

I am using ionic 1.4.2 to develop an app on android. And the ionic keyboard plugin is used.

I met with this issue: in a login page, if the input is clicked(focused), the form will not be scrolled to the center, however if I type the keyboard to input a character, the form will be scrolled to the center.

On iOS, no such issue.

```
<ion-content  scroll="true" overflow-scroll="false" class="loginDiv" ng-show="loginViewVisible">

<form></form>


</ion-content>

<ion-content>other elements</ion-content>
```

Comment: what does it mean  "if the input is clicked,"?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Focused. The cursor shows.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed any idea?

Comment: what i understand you mean to say that if you just focus input field, keyboard does not push layout up and when you start typing then keyboard pushes the layout and now you can see the input field?Is it like this?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed yep. Correct

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below lines of code in your config file.

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Config file can be found as 
android xml path: app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

And further more please check you app.js file for keyboard plug in if they are set as mention below or not

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
```

Hope it will help.